# I'm following an answer that you posted on another site

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

"This answer is no longer accurate because the description and the behavior of the option underneath "Enable autofill..." has changed. The functionality to save passwords locally has been replaced with 'Google Smart Lock', a Google product to transfer your passwords to a Google server for their perusal. Opting in to this product is different from getting Google Chrome to update its (pre-Smart Lock) saved passwords, which you can no longer do from within the program itself."

Question:  does this mean that I have to reset my password file on the Google server in some manner?  I'm having the problem of having deleted the site locally, yet Chrome still fills-in the old password.

Answer (score 0):

Opening this: [chrome://settings/passwords](http://chrome://settings/passwords) should give you the list of passwords saved on the device and the Google Account if you have enabled Sync.

In your case, you can check out the passwords in your smart lock account by going to the following link and logging in with your Google Account credentials.

https://passwords.google.com

You can then remove the password (from both of these lists) and re-enter it on the website.

Chrome will ask you to save the new credentials and will use these in future.